# Performance of simple SELECT operation on big (2 GB) table

Tags: mysql

I've really simple query to get MIN and MAX values, it looks like:

```
SELECT  MAX(value_avg)
      , MIN(value_avg) 
FROM value_data 
WHERE value_id = 769 
  AND time_id BETWEEN 214000 AND 219760;
```

And here you are the schema of the value_data table:

```
CREATE TABLE `value_data` (
  `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `value_min` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `value_avg` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `value_max` float DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_vdata_vid` (`value_id`),
  KEY `idx_vdata_tid` (`time_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you see, the query and the table are simple and I don't see anything wrong here, but when I execute this query, it takes about ~9 seconds to get data. I also made profile of this query, and 99% of time is "Sending data".

The table is really big and it weighs about 2 GB, but is it a problem? I don't think this table is too big, it must be something else...

Comment: Whow, MySQL Must be total crap when a 2gb table is big. Really. Ever seen a table with billions of rows in Terabyte size? I assume that isa Combo on your end of (a) slow disc and (b) not enough RAM.

Comment: Your "simple" query needs to access every matching row to read `value_avg`. How many rows are we talking about? What's the explain plan? (BTW, how comes the table has no primary key?)

Comment: checkout CPU Usage on ur db server while this query is getting executed. Is it hitting 100% ! Also run ANALYZE on this table.

Comment: It should not - i assume it is safe to say he has a Memory Problem, too, so this Ends up pulling the whole table from disc. 2gb in Memory Cache would not atake 9 seconds to run along the data. Running an OLAP query from a likely low end disc Subsystem - there you go.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can easily handle a database of that size.  However, you should be able to improve the performance of this query and probably the table in general.  By changing the `time_id` column to an `UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL`, you can significantly decrease the size of the data and indexes on that column.  Also, the query you mention could benefit from a composite index on `(value_id, time_id)`.  With that index, it would be able to use the index for both parts of the query instead of just one as it is now.

Also, please edit your question with an `EXPLAIN` of the query.  It should confirm what I expect about the indexes, but it's always helpful information to have.

Edit:

You don't have a `PRIMARY` index defined for the table, which definitely isn't helping your situation.  If the values of `(value_id, time_id)` are unique, you should probably make the new composite index I mention above the `PRIMARY` index for the table.